# Adding columns based on a specific function with (l)apply or purr on lists in a list?

Tags: r, list, apply

I want to add columns based on a function in all lists in list.

```
list1 <- list(A = c(1:10), B = c(rnorm(1:10)), C = c(rnorm(1:10)), D = c(rnorm(1:10)))
list2 <- list(A = c(1:10), B = c(rnorm(1:10)), C = c(rnorm(1:10)), D = c(rnorm(1:10)))
both_lists <- list(list1,list2)
both_lists <- lapply(both_lists, function(x) ... )
```

For one dataframe (not in a list) I normally use:

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = c(1:10), B = c(rnorm(1:10)), C = c(rnorm(1:10)), D = c(rnorm(1:10)))
df2 <- data.frame(A = c(1:10), B = c(rnorm(1:10)), C = c(rnorm(1:10)), D = c(rnorm(1:10)))
df1 %>% mutate(max = do.call(pmax, c(select(., c(2:4)))))
```

But how do I do this for the lists* in the list? So I want to do 2 things to all the lists in my list:

- find the maximum of columns 2-4
- add that maximum as a separate row

Oh and could anyone also tell me how I actually change the name of the list inside the list? (So changing the name of list1 to the name of a row name in the set? EG setting the name of list to `df1[[1]][1]` and repeat that with lapply for every list in the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `lapply` you can do it as follows:

```
lapply(both_lists, function(x){x[['max']] <- do.call(pmax, x[2:4]); x})
```

The output looks like this:

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$A
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

[[1]]$B
 [1]  1.325128799  0.341702207  0.341139152 -0.630065889  0.799934566  0.427531770
 [7] -1.492861023  2.643621022  0.008158055 -0.187956774

[[1]]$C
 [1] -0.8535937 -0.1753520  1.1008905 -0.0385363 -1.6739434  0.2179597 -0.1300490  0.4177869
 [9]  1.3066992  0.2369493

[[1]]$D
 [1]  0.98472409  0.66930725  0.52449977  0.08553770 -1.81759549 -0.07564249 -0.63611958
 [8] -1.19293507 -1.61571223  1.29777033

[[1]]$max
 [1]  1.3251288  0.6693073  1.1008905  0.0855377  0.7999346  0.4275318 -0.1300490  2.6436210
 [9]  1.3066992  1.2977703


[[2]]
...
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! Would you also know how to change the names of list1, list2, etc. to the first row name (of the first column) which I think would be ```df1[[1]][1]``` ?

Comment: `df1[[1]][1]` is  a single number `1`. I am not sure what you mean by the first row name. I suggest asking a separate question with a small reproducible example (with expected output).

Comment: Will do, I'm not even sure if I can rename lists in a list in r? Since it gives [[1]] or [[2]] when I use: ```View(both_lists)```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `data.frame`s `df1` and `df2` as shown in the OP are in a `list` named `dfl`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

dfl <- lapply(dfl, function(x){
  x %<>% mutate(max = do.call(pmax, c(select(., c(2:4)))))
})
```

And if you want to set the names of the `list` elements as some value from the `data.frame`s within, maybe something like this?

```
names(dfl) <- lapply(dfl, function(x){
  x[2,2]
})
```

I hope this is what you actually meant because your question was a bit unclear to me. (Apologies if I am wrong.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Mutate doesn't work here because it of the list class. Second one also didn't work. I think for the second one I maybe need to add something like this, but I don't know how I should do this exactly:
```both_lists_2 <- lapply(both_lists, function(x){names(both_lists) <- both_lists$list1[[x]][2]; x})```

Comment: Sorry but I had understood "But how do I do this for the dataframes in the list?" to mean you had a `list` of `data.frame`s? Both solutions assumed this. So do you basically have a `list` of `list`s wherein each `list` contains several `data.frame`s?

Comment: No problem, I had written it like that, my mistake! Changed it. Yes, I have a list with lists (I changed the dataframes to lists since it would be more flexible (but I'm having a harder time with it since I'm very very much used to dataframes and not at all to lists).

Comment: Is this what you want to do w.r.t. naming? `names(both_lists) <- lapply(both_lists, function(x){x[[1]][1]})`?